Cannot upgrade nuget package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource from 8.0.0 to 8.0.1
At this point, this is a somewhat rhetorical question, because I already have the answer, which I will post later for anyone else who has this same problem.
I have a project that has been using System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource version 8.0.0.  Because some other packages have never been updated, they are still requesting version 5.0.0.  Therefore my project has a binding redirect to make everybody use 8.0.0:
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

I was tasked with our regular update of nuget packages to the latest and greatest versions.  Other packages update just fine, but this one doesn't.
At first, I forgot to update the binding redirect, and got runtime errors:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Neither version 8.0.0.0 or 5.0.0.0 can be found.  This was supposed to be handled by the binding redirect, but it no longer works because I updated the package.
So I tried updating the binding redirect:
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.1.0" newVersion="8.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>

But this still doesn't work.  The binding still cannot find version 8.0.1.0 or 5.0.0.0:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=8.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

If no one else knows how to fix this, I will self-answer as soon as Stack Overflow lets me.

The solution is in the version numbers.
Package was upgraded from "8.0.0" to "8.0.1".
Binding redirect was upgraded from "8.0.0.0" to "8.0.1.0".
It turns out that Microsoft in all their wisdom, doesn't use the same version numbers for the shared libraries as the package that contains them.
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource package "8.0.0" contains DLL version "8.0.0.0".  Simple enough.
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource package "8.0.1" does NOT contain DLL version "8.0.1.0", instead it contains DLL version "8.0.0.1".
Setting the binding redirect to the DLL version fixes the problem:
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.1" newVersion="8.0.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>

